# Getting value of ID from class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class

How would you retrieve the value of the ID tag using its class name in jQuery.

I am trying the following code but it returns value `undefined`.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea id='5' class='cp _check'>sometexthere</textarea>
    </body>
<html>
```

And calling it using the following function:

```
function updatecontent() {
    var check = $('.cp _check').('#id').val();
    alert(check);
}
```

The `alert` box returns value as `undefined`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Since you want to obtain the value of the `id` HTML attribute, I would emphasize that and go with `attr()`:

```
var id = $(".cp._check").attr("id");
```

Your class selector is also incorrect: since your element exposes both the `cp` and the `_check` classes, it should be `.cp._check` instead of `.cp _check` (which would match the `<_check>` elements that are descendants of elements that expose the `cp` class).

Comment: - thanks...this worked...really appreciate the swift responses. thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr()`:

```
$(".cp_check").attr("ID");
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3WHqS/*

---

It's also perhaps worth nothing your HTML markup has 2 classes, `cp` and `_check`. You need to remove the whitespace between the 2 for this to become 1 class: `cp_check`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `id` for the first element containing the classes `.cp` and `._check`.

```
$('.cp._check')[0].id;
```

Or alternatively:

```
$('.cp._check')[0].getAttribute('id');
$('.cp._check').get(0).id;

// These two are quite a bit slower
$('.cp._check').attr('id');
$('.cp._check').prop('id'); // newer versions of jQuery
```

FYI classes can't contain spaces, if you meant the single class `cp_check` then use `$('.cp_check')`.